# What's this substance that was found fully-enclosed in a eucalyptus blank?

Tags: turning, woodturning

This glassy, opaque item was deep inside a eucalyptus blank. There was no indication from the outside of the wood that there was anything inside, so it must have been grown over while the tree was alive.[image: closeup]

It appears to be connected to / part of a small branch that was trapped inside; does anyone have any idea what it might be? It didn't chip like glass, and was only slightly harder than the surrounding wood.[image: wider shot before removing the material]

Comment: Looks like sap/resin that trees produce when they are damaged (e.g. by grown in branches)

Comment: Yup, sap. Smaller bark and sap/resin inclusions aren't rare, although they occur more commonly in some species than others.

Comment: @KromstersayssupportMonica, how do you change your user name? Is it something any moderator can do?

Comment: @Graphus anyone can change his/her display name on SO. Open your profile (link on top-right) -> "Edit profile and settings" tab -> "Display name". Your SE name stays the same iirc, but it's never displayed afaik.

Comment: @KromstersayssupportMonica, thanks!

Comment: @GraphussupportsMonica nice to see you support of Monica situation too!

Comment: @KromstersayssupportMonica, honestly I can't imagine any reasonable person wouldn't!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like sap/resin that trees produce when they are damaged (e.g. by grown-in branches). It indeed hardens over time and can be trapped within the growing tree.

Comment: Thanks! Googling around a bit more, I think it is "kino" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kino_(botany) ) - I was surprised that it could harden into such a glassy form...

Comment: It's quite akin to amber btw

Comment: Akin to the *starting point* of amber. Amber is fossilised.